# How to validate radio button and text field javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<form action="script.php" method="post" id="Form1">
<input name="radioGroup" type="radio" value="Radio1" id="Radio1id">
<input name="radioGroup" type="radio" value="Radio2" id="Radio2id">
<input name="radioGroup" type="radio" value="Radio3" id="Radio3id">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" size="30" id="name" placeholder="Name*"><br>
<input type="text" size="30" id="email" placeholder="Email*"><br>
<input type="text" size="30" id="comments" placeholder="Comments (Optional)"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to validate radio button and text filed at same time. for an example if radio button is not checked or text field not used. should get a alert window.

Thanks,

Comment: Use jQuery validator for robust validation support.

Comment: Have you tried validating with Javascript. This question will get downvoted as it has been answered numerous times. Please add the JS code that you've tried so far.

Comment: Your can use the "required" attribute to make the input required, before the form is submitted. Just add `required="true"` to the fields you want to make mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like that, or use JQuery because is easy to use for validation

```
if((document.getElementById('Radio1id').checked) && document.getElementById('name').value != "") {
 //Action for checked radio button and text box without value
}else if(document.getElementById('Radio2id').checked) {
 //Another Action . . . 
}

if((document.getElementById('Radio1id').checked == false) && document.getElementById('name').value != "") {
 //Action for NON checked radio button and text box without value
}
```

Comment: In JS use for logical operator AND -> &&, I write it directly from head, but logic is ok, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

by using jQuery.

```
 // valid syntax for jQuery
 $("#Radio1id").is(":checked"); // for radio button
 $("#email").val()===""; // for any input
```

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery Validator](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) , gives you more feature and choices down the road with any project. Plus, you can ask questions on GitHub.